# Insert records into Spark SQL table

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created spark SQL table like below through Azure Databricks:

```
create table sample1(price double)
```

Actual file has data like 'abc' instead of double value.

While inserting `'abc'` string value into `double` column it accepts as `NULL` without any failure. My concern is why are we not getting any error? I want to failure message in this case.

Please let me know if I'm missing something. I want to disable the implicit conversion of datatypes.

Comment: Well, it might depend on your code how this error is handled. But as you haven't provided a single line of your implementation, its pretty hard to spot the error

Comment: Actually i have my target table with price column Double as datatype. I have my actual data in one another table without inferschema so i may got the value 'abc' in price column. Now problem is while inserting the actual data into my target table it got the wrong data 'abc' as 'null' in silent manner. I want to force fail in this case. It simple as "Insert into select column" im using.

Comment: If you want the insert to fail, you maybe have to write some code for this.

Comment: Could you please tell me what kind of code? It won't fail like Microsoft sql server or other database systems?

Comment: Well, how do you actually import something? Is there any code involved?

Comment: Yes, reading the data from file into Pyspark dataframe and creating the actual data table which will be our temporary source for target table

Comment: And you still don't want to share a single line of that code such that others could check it, nor provide sample data to reproduce the problem?

Comment: This is the code for creating table with actual data,

sourceFile = spark.read.format("csv").load(StagingFiletoBeValidated, header=True, charset="ISO-8859-1")
 sourceFile .write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable(str('stg'+StagingFileName))

Comment: The below code is creating target table with fixed schema and inserting records from actual data table,

 spark.sql("drop table IF EXISTS src"+FileName)
    spark.sql("CREATE TABLE src"+FileName+" AS SELECT "+SRCCol+" FROM "+FileName)
    spark.sql("INSERT INTO src"+FileName+" SELECT "+SRCCol+" FROM stg"+StagingFileName)

Comment: All the attributes like column name and table name will be inserted in dynamic way.